# How to programatically go one level up of the route hierarchy with React router 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have one functional requirement in my project that it should have a back button which will navigate user to one level up of the route hierarchy.

Consider I have following routes:

```
// Home Component
<div>
    <Route path="/courses" component={CourseComponent} />
    <Route path="/settings" component={SettingsComponent} />
</div>
```

Nested routes:

```
// Course Component
<Switch>
    <Route path={`${match.path}/:courseId/details`} component={CourseDetailComponent} />
    <Route path={`${match.path}/classes`} component={ClassComponent} />
    <Route
        exact
        path={match.path}
        render={() => <h3>Courses...</h3>}
    />
</Switch>
```

Now I want to navigate user from `CourseDetailComponent` to `CourseComponent` using that back button.

> Note: I can't use `history` since this will use browser history considering the case: if user directly land on a page using a URL.

Comment: I suspect that you need to do it manually. Maybe get the current url and remove the last path

Comment: Considering `${match.path}/:courseId/details` url, removing last path will not solve the problem! I was wondering if `react-router-v5` provide something like that or not otherwise I have to do it myself!

Comment: You can issue a back navigation, but this only goes to the previous page the user was on. So you are left with using `history.push` or `history.replace` and passing a computed path. The issue here though is that you *don't* want to simply remove the last path segment. You'll need some custom logic. Where is the back button being rendered in your UI? Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] if you still need to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one component in your App, which knows all the changes. So, you can have a parent App component, which will be notified from all changes

```
<Route component={App}>
  {/* ... other routes */
</Route>

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return { showBackButton: false }
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    var routeChanged = nextProps.location !== this.props.location
    this.setState({ showBackButton: routeChanged })
  }
})
```

Reference here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1066#issuecomment-139233328

Comment: This will only tell the application if user landed directly on that page or not, but this is not what I am looking for! I want to go to parent route of that child route whatever be the window history is.

Comment: If this will be in your root, the component will always be activated. You can tract it from there. You just need to put all your routes inside a component like this

Comment: Are you suggesting to create a map of all routes used in my application?